# Loading a large file into an array of String in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, string, large-files

My app needs to load large files (3 to 7 MB of text) into arrays of String, i.e., one string per line.

The simple way to go is to use componentsSeparatedByString or componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet (or their Swift counterparts) as follows:

```
array = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Everything works as it should, except that for large enough files and old enough devices, times are unacceptably long. Just to be clear, it takes 2+ seconds to create the array on an iPad 4th gen, and 8+ seconds on an iPhone 4.

Since I can't change the hardware of the customers and I can't change componentsSeparatedBy..., is there a way I could speed this up?
Perhaps having on disk, instead of the text file, something closer to an array of String (which would maybe load faster)? If so, how?

(Swift solutions are welcome, too)

Comment: It would help if you explained why you need such a large array of strings all loaded at once into memory.

Comment: The app needs to do lots of comparisons and computations between all those strings at once, so they all need to be loaded into memory. Note that loading an array this size is not a problem with newer hardware (like iPhone 6). What I do in memory with the array works fast even with an iPhone 4. It's the creation of the array that takes long.